# Autohotkey v2 script | copy, open an application, paste

Tags: autohotkey, ahk2

I would like to select text, press a hotkey to trigger an application open, paste the selected text into the newly opened application. In my case, my application is called [everything](https://www.voidtools.com/), a file locator on windows. It was stored under D drive, and updated to the latest version.

Here is my code:

```
#f::
{
    A_Clipboard := ""
    ; Copy selected text to clipboard
    Send "^c"
    ClipWait ; Wait for 2 seconds for clipboard to contain text
    SetTitleMatchMode 2
    
    if WinExist("*everything*")
        {
        WinActivate 
        MsgBox "Everything was found."
        }
        ; Use the window found by WinExist.
    else {
        Run "D:\Downloads\everything\Everything.exe"
        Sleep 1000  
        SendInput A_Clipboard
        Send "^v"
        MsgBox "Everything was not found."
        }    
}
```

This script copies the selected text, opens the application.
The problem is that it does not paste the selected text into Everything.

If I press ctrl+V manually, the selected text will paste into the search window in Everything. WinExist can not find Everything, I tested with a message box. The winTitle of Everything is "everything.exe".

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Try `Run "D:\Downloads\everything\Everything.exe" " -s " A_Clipboard `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

#f::
{ 
    A_Clipboard := ""
    ; Copy selected text to clipboard
    Send "^c"
    if !ClipWait(2)
    {
        MsgBox "The attempt to copy text onto the clipboard failed."
        return
    }   
    Run "D:\Downloads\everything\Everything.exe" " -s `"" A_Clipboard "`""
}
```

Comment: Hi, 
When I select multiple words (like an article title) to search, I would run into a pop-up box by Everything. It states "Unable to open the file list: D:\Downloads\AutoHotKey\scripts\(the first word of the selected words) is not a valid file list. And in the search window, only the first word was pasted.

Comment: Strategies to maintain skeletal muscle mass in the injured athlete Nutritional considerations and exercise mimetics. It is just an example. Any multiple words will yield the pop-up box by Everything.